# Video transmission over UDP between sender and client (preferably using application FEC-code)?

Tags: c++, network-programming, udp

Is anyone aware of any implementation which is combining a FEC-implementation of LDPC-code (e.g. OpenFEC (www.openfec.org)), a server socket and client socket?
I want to do have one application, which is deployed at one computer sending packets encoded with FEC; and another application deployed at another computer decoding the FEC-encoded packets.

The capabilities should preferably be as the current scripts used for performance test included in OpenFEC, but with the above additions.
Preferably video should be sent. I guess that I'll use the EvalVID+-framework for that.

I wonder if anyone has any good code of the above or anything similar that I can reuse or any advice to give.

Thanks!

Comment: Hi Anders. I don't know of an open implementation, but I've worked for a company that does that commercially. They are Israeli and their product works great, you can contact them maybe, or look up their white papers. http://giraffic.com/

Comment: Hi Dvir / שלום דויר : )
Thanks for your input!
My current plan is to do it from scratch using the FFMpeg-library and OpenFEC-library.

Shalom from Rechovot, Israel